# Downloading New Files Added in FTP Automatically With Bash Script

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, ftp, file-transfer

I am getting files which added to a path by FTP manually with below script:
As files in this path are loaded daily I want to able this code to run daily at a specific time and just make the script, remember to just download new files not whole the files which are available in a path.
#!/bin/bash
HOST=ftp.example.com
USER=ftpuser
PASSWORD="*****"

```
ftp -inv $HOST <<EOF
user $USER $PASSWORD
cd /path/to/file
mget *.html
bye
EOF
```

Comment: How do you know which files are old and which are new?  Are new files always added daily?  You could list the directory and order by date and pull only the latest based on some if-block

Comment: yes they are adding daily and i want to know is there any way to use the time of the file from LS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone who needs:
This has been solved via below code:
Firstly I connect to FTP server then I save the name and time of the file loaded in separated text file and then compare my system time with the time of loaded file, so with this code I can download new files automatically.

```
#!/bin/bash


use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;

# Login credentials

user='*****' #Do not forget to enclose inside single or double quotes

pass='*****'

directory='/RemoteDirectory/'

host='IP'



# Set time

# perl -e 'print time' will return the current time in Unix epoch format

# So if you substract 43200, that should give you the current time minus 30 minutes in Unix epoch format:

time=$(perl -e 'print time-43200')



# Connect to host and download the listing of the remote directory

ftp -n $host <<END_GET_LIST

        quote USER $user

        quote PASS $pass

        cd $directory

        ls -l /LocalDirectory/ftpList.txt

        quit

END_GET_LIST

# Disconnect from remote host



# Save the 6th, 7th, and 8th field of the directory listing (i.e. Aug 15 5:15) of each line into file Dates.txt

awk -F ' ' '{print $6,$7,$8}' /LocalDirectory/ftpList.txt > /LocalDirectory/'Dates.txt'



# Save the 9th field of the directory listing (file name) of each line into file Files.txt

awk -F ' ' '{print $9}' /LocalDirectory/ftpList.txt > /LocalDirectory/'Files.txt'



linenum=0 #Auxiliary variable for sed.



while read list; do

        linenum=$((linenum+1))

        #Convert the modification datetime of each file to Unix's epoch

        epoch=$(perl -MFile::stat -e "print stat('$list')->mtime")

        if [ $epoch -gt $time ] ; then

                file=$(sed -n "${linenum}p" Files.txt)  #If the condition is satisfied, use sed to get the name of the file

                 #in the same line of Files.txt.

#Connect again and download file when the condition above has been satisfied.

                ftp -n $host <<END_RETRIEVE

                        quote USER $user

                        quote PASS $pass

                        cd $directory

                        get $file

                        quit

END_RETRIEVE

        fi

done < /LocalDirectory/'Dates.txt'
```